# What happens if I exile The Grand Calcutron with Do-It-Yourself Seraph?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-joke-cards

Let's take a look at [The Grand Calcutron](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bThe%20Grand%20Calcutron%5d) and [Do-It-Yourself Seraph](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bDo-It-Yourself%20Seraph%5d).

As you see from Calcutron's third ability, the "program" is treated like a zone, into which the cards of your hand are moved into.

While it doesn't say it on the card, Wizards stated the cards in the players' program are moved back to their hands if The Grand Calcultron leaves the battlefield.

What happens if I have The Grand Calculatron in my library and put Do-It-Yourself Seraph into play, attack, and exile the Calculatron with it?

Answer (score 6):

Players are initially unable to play cards.

---

The Seraph gains the following ability:

> When The Grand Calcutron enters the battlefield, each player's hand becomes a program (an ordered row of revealed cards).

It will never trigger because Seraph is already on the battelfield when it gains the ability.

---

The Seraph gains the following ability:

> Players can only play the first card of their program.

Players are unable to play cards (play lands or cast cards) except the first card of their program. Since nothing placed cards in their programs, they are initially unable to play cards.

---

The Seraph gains the following abilities:

> If a card would be put into a player's hand from anywhere, that player reveals it and places it anywhere within his or her program instead.
>
> At the beginning of each player's end step, if that player's program has fewer than five cards, he or she draws cards equal to the difference.

These provide means of adding cards to one's program, allowing the players to play cards again.

In particular, the cards in one's hand are not counted when counting the cards in one's program.